# Tree command list one level all files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, tree

How can I use the tree command to list current directory as a tree?

If I do

```
tree -L 1
```

It only lists the directories, how can I get it to show the files as well?

Comment: What OS is this for?  `/L` is not a valid switch for Windows XP.

Comment: OS is Linux - Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, that was a waste of an answer.  Maybe my Ubuntu VM can help me top it off.

Comment: `tree -L 1` will list **both** file and directories. If you have no files in the current directory or hidden files (`.*` prefix), they will not show up by default.

Comment: My issue was hidden files.... ;(  I can only hope it was an early morning Brain Fart...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Windows XP or 7, the `/F` switch will also show filenames.

```
C:\>tree /?
Graphically displays the folder structure of a drive or path.

TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```

However, I'm guessing you're on another OS since `/L` is not a valid switch on XP or 7.

On my Ubuntu VM (11.10), `tree` did not come pre-installed.  `sudo apt-get install tree` fixed that quickly.  Afterwards `tree -L 1` worked just as you seem to want it to - it showed a tree of just the current directory, including files *and* directories.  Adding the `-a` switch also included "hidden" files.  It seems the default behavior of `tree` is to show both files and directories.  This can be changed to directories only with the `-d` switch.

More details can be found in `man tree` or here:  http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm

If you're having trouble, I suggest checking the `ls` of your `pwd` to make sure there actually *are* files in that directory.  Also, check your file and folder permissions and view the `man` page for `tree` for more options.

Answer (score 27):

It lists both files and directories for me:

```
[ben@ben-x220 ~/tmp/test]$ tree --version
tree v1.5.3 (c) 1996 - 2009 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher, Kyosuke Tokoro 

[ben@ben-x220 ~/tmp/test]$ tree -L 1
.
├── dir1
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3

1 directory, 3 files

[ben@ben-x220 ~/tmp/test]$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   └── file4
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3

1 directory, 4 files
```